# ランダムに複数引いた通路の幅が同じになるように整形する方法

Tags: アルゴリズム

ランダムでダンジョンのマップを作成しようとしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上の画像のように２つの部屋があり、その間を、2マスの幅がある通路でつなぎます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

通路の始点、終点や折れ曲がる地点はランダムで決まります。
さらに通路を追加します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

二度目以降に通路を追加する際、以前に引いた通路を気にせずに引くので、以前に引いた通路と一部が重なったり、隣り合ったりする場合があります。

こうして2、3回通路を引いた後で、通路の幅がどの場所でも2マスになるように、自動的に通路を整形したいです。
具体的には、以下の2つの条件を満たすようにしたいです。

1.通路内に3x3マスの空間を含まないこと。
2.2x2マスの大きさのキャラクターが、左部屋のどの出口から出ても、右部屋に行けること。また、右部屋のどの出口から出ても、左部屋に行けること。

2x2マスの大きさのキャラクターは、上下左右斜め方向に1マスずつ動きます。
ただし下の画像のような地形を、左下->右上、右上->左下に移動することはできません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どのようなアルゴリズムで整形すれば良いでしょうか？

追記
部屋と通路のエリアは区別されます。
通路部分の矩形範囲が与えられて、その中で通路を整形したいです。

プレイヤーは1マスの大きさですが、敵キャラクターに、1マスのものと2マスのものがいます。

Comment: 素朴な疑問ですが `部屋` と `通路` って区別されるんですか？複数通路を引いた場合に部屋と区別が付きにくくなったり、アルゴリズムを上手に設計しないと部屋が通路として縮小されそうですが……

Comment: 既存の通路を追加するアルゴリズムはどうなっているのでしょうか？また、通路の幅やキャラの大きさは奇数幅の方が「中心」ができて当たり判定的なものもやりやすいんじゃないかなぁというのが素人の感想です(全体の設計に関わってくると思うので無理にとは言いませんが)。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。情報を追記しました

Comment: 興味深い質問だと思うのですが、定石のような物がないとすると、回答が付きづらいかも知れないですね。思い付く方法はあるけれど、それが回答にする価値があるか解らない、という人もいるのではないでしょうか（私もとりあえず、というレベルでは思い付く方法はあります）。回答を書いても、「それは当然思い付いているのだけれど、もっとスッキリした方法を探しています」と言う話かも知れませんので。つまり、質問者さんが検討した方法が全て、途中でもいいので質問に記載されていると、回答が得られ易くなるかなと思います。

Comment: 直接の回答ではありませんが、質問に記載のある2つの条件を満たす通路を作ることが目的なのであれば、通路を作成後に整形するよりは、通路を作成している最中に3x3の空間が発生するかチェックして発生する方向には通路を引かない、（通路を引ける場所がない場合バックトラック）というようにする方が早いかと思います。

Comment: 「3x3な箇所を見つけたら，そのエリア内の何れかのマスを非通路化する必要がある」っていう話なのであれば，【実際にどれかを非通路化してみて→経路がふさがらないかどうか調べる】っていう原始的な総当たり的なのをまずはやってみれば良いのでは？　で，そこで実際に生じた問題について問うべきであろう．少なくとも，単に「効率がどうの…」いう話なのかそれとも「それだと行き詰るから」という話なのかくらいは明確にされたい．

Answer (score 1):

２本で引くのではなく１本で引いて、複数の通路を引く際は重なりを意識する。
出来上がった後に縦横を倍にすればできませんか？

```
0000000000000000000000
0111100000000000000000
0111111111111110000000
0111100000000011111110
0111111111111111111110
0111100000000011111110
0000000000000000000000
```

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00111111110000000000000000000000000000000000
00111111110000000000000000000000000000000000
00111111111111111111111111111100000000000000
00111111111111111111111111111100000000000000
00111111110000000000000000001111111111111100
00111111110000000000000000001111111111111100
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00111111111111111111111111111111111111111100
00111111110000000000000000001111111111111100
00111111110000000000000000001111111111111100
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: もし、幅 1 で道を引いた後に幅を 2 にすればよいとおっしゃっているのであれば、2 つの道が並行に並びつつ距離 1 を保っているときに不都合が生じるように思います。

Comment: 内容を追記しました。

Comment: なるほど地図全体を拡大するという意味だったのですね。なるほどです、追記ありがとうございます。質問文にあるような奇数長を含む道は引けなくなりますが割り切りとしてはアリそうです。